# Unable to ajax update component with p:commandLink click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have three options for user: two equipment selection and one option to say I don't want equipment. To select two equipment I used `p:commandLink`. To say I do not want equipment I used `h:selectOneRadio`.

If user do not want to buy equipment, user can select the option button 'I do not wish to have'. So at anytime, only one button can be selected within the three of them.

If I press `h:selectOneRadio` button, then other two buttons (`p:commandLink`) are updating properly to 'select'. But if I select an equipment (`p:commandLink`), then `h:selectOneRadio` button is not deselecting even though it's bean value is updated to false.

JSF page

```
<h:panelGroup id="pwpPanel">
    <div class="row">
        <ui:repeat value="#{reconBean.EQList}" var="equipment">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn-fibre-tab text-center">
                    <ui:fragment rendered="#{reconBean.pwpSelectedEquipmentID != equipment.id }">
                        <p:commandLink id="selectpwp" process="@form" update=":mainForm:pwpPanel"
                            styleClass="select_button" action="#{reconBean.updatePWPItem(equipment.id)}"
                            immediate="true">
                            Select
                            <f:ajax render=":mainForm:pwpPanel" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </ui:fragment>
                    <ui:fragment rendered="#{reconBean.pwpSelectedEquipmentID eq equipment.id }">
                        <p:commandLink id="selectedpwp" process="@form" update=":mainForm:pwpPanel"
                            styleClass="selected_button" action="#{reconBean.updatePWPItem(equipment.id)}"
                            immediate="true">
                            Selected
                            <f:ajax render=":mainForm:pwpPanel" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </ui:fragment>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{reconBean.notPurchaseWithPurchase}" id="radioDoNotWant"
                name="pwpEquipment">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="I do not wish to have" itemValue="true" />
                <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{reconBean.resetPWPSelection}"
                    render="pwpPanel" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Bean values

```
public void updatePWPItem(String itemID) {
    pwpSelectedEquipmentID = itemID;
    notPurchaseWithPurchase = false;
}

public void resetPWPSelection(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    pwpSelectedEquipmentID = null;
}
```

Comment: you can at least with 100% certainty remove the `f:ajax` in the `p:commandLink`s. Might even be a fix.

Comment: @Kukeltje   No, It didn't work like that too.

Comment: Then create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is the *immediate* attribute set to *true* on the *CommandLinks*. It is essentially to understand the [The Lifecycle of a JavaServer Faces Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html). The impact of the immediate attribute differs in, on what kind of component it is applied. As stated in a [good article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html):

> In the standard JSF lifecycle, the action attribute on an Command component is evaluated in the Invoke Application phase

... if you set `immediate="true"` on it.

To be honest, i do not exacly know why this prevents your radio option from being unchecked (I am still learning all aspects of the JSF lifecylce), but i think it is because it remains unchanged in the component tree and gets rendered as it was even if the model is updated through your action (if someone may comment on this i will update accordingly).

**The solution** to your problem is to remove the *immediate* attribute from your *CommandLinks* or set it to *false*.

**Some remarks:**

- PrimeFaces *CommandLinks* have build in AJAX capabilities which are enabled by default. There is no need to enclose an additional `<f:ajax />`. Only if you want to disable AJAX you have to set its *ajax* attribute to *false*. The *render* attribute of *Ajax* conforms to the *update* attribute of *CommandLink*.
- You are using *SelectOneRadio* in a context it is not designed for. As stated on [JSFToolbox](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneRadio.html):

  > This component is designed for situations where you want to display a mutually exclusive list of options to the user as a set of radio buttons.

  Consider using another better suited component like *CommandLink* or *CommandButton*.

Comment: if I remove `immediate="true"` the action is not calling at all when button click.

Comment: @imesh I do not see anything obvious that may cause this from the code provided so far. Did you get any error messages and/or exceptions? Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/3736575) and follow instructions.